# Timer from 00:00:00 using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I am trying to get a timer to start from 00:00:00 (minutes:seconds:milliseconds) and count up. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076409/iphone-ios-how-to-add-a-running-countup-display-timer-to-an-app-like-clock-stop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187478/truncate-nsdate-zero-out-time) but I can't get it to quite work, it displays the current time and date.

My code is as follows:

```
- (void)timerTicked:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:date];
    NSDate* dateOnly = [[calendar dateFromComponents:components] dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]secondsFromGMT]];

    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    if (!dateFormatter) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"mm:ss:SS";
    }

    self.timerLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateOnly];
}
```

Comment: That code has nothing to do with what you want to do.  Think about what you need to do:  Store a start date reference, then on every tick of the timer subtract the current time from the start time and show that (You can reuse portions of the code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a detailed outline of what to do:

Create an instance variable of type NSDate that you will use to record the start time. Let's call that variable startTime;

Write a startTimer method that:

- Save the current time to startTime.
- Starts a timer that fires every second, or whatever update
  interval you want. It can call your timerTicked method.

In your timerTicked method, save the current date in a local variable "now".

Use the NSCalendar method `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` to calculate the number of minutes and seconds since the timer started.

For milliseconds, you'll probably have to do your own calculation, something like this:

```
NSTimeInterval elapsedSeconds = [now timeIntervalSinceDate: startTime];
milliseconds = floor(1000*(elapsedSeconds-floor(elapsedSeconds)));
```

Comment: There is no need to deal with `NSCalendar and components. You can safely calculate the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds from the `elapsedSeconds` value.

Comment: Yup, true enough. I started out outlining it that way, and then figured I should use the OPs NSCalendar based approach