# How do you display real time, time on UIView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a alarm clock app but I don't know how to display the time in real time. Would I have to do that programmatically or using an object like UIDatePicker? I have tried searching for it but it is all for Objective-C which I am not at all familiar with.

If you have any questions please comment them down below.

Comment: Did you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076409/add-a-running-countup-display-timer-to-an-ios-app-like-the-clock-stopwatch

Comment: @SharonNathaniel yes I saw this post but I didn't understand what it was saying.

Comment: If you look at the answer its pretty simple, you need to take a time control with time interval of 1.0 second. This timer will execute a function - (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer that will display current time. Since timer will execute this every time , you will be able to get current time in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = NSDate()
var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
println(outputFormat.stringFromDate(date))
```

Comment: on the third line it says that there is an error: `Expected Declaration`

Comment: be sure to import UIKit

Comment: I want to give the date value to the Label like so `var date = NSDate()
    
    mainTimeLabel.text = date` but it gives an error saying expected declaration

Comment: mainTimeLabel.text = outputFormat.stringFromDate(date)

Comment: this is in my project, not the playground and it still throws an error `expected declaration`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63740/discussion-between-grapeapplesauce-and-steve-rosenberg).